# Why do I get infinite recursion warning in this piece of code, despite it not being infinite?

Tags: java, recursion, netbeans

So I wrote a piece of code that is supposed to catch wrong format of input, and ask the user for correction. It works correctly, does exactly what it is supposed to do, but Netbeans throws "the method `validate` will recurse infinitely" warning. I tested it thoroughly and it does not indeed recurse infinitely, so I would like to know what possibly makes Netbeans think that it will.

Edit: I realized now that the `int validatedInput = 0;` is culpript here. If user enters char, it is still set to zero and the loop breaks off. But my main point is still why Netbeans actually thinks this piece of code has possibility of recursing infinitely, despite there are constraints in place that prevent it.

Here is the following method(note that `maxBound` is always predefined by array lenght):

```
public static int validate(int maxBound) {
    int controlVar = maxBound;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean wrongInputLoopThrough = false;
    int validatedInput = 0;
    do {
        if (wrongInputLoopThrough) {
            System.out.println("Integer value is out of bound! Please repeat your input.");
        }
        try {
            validatedInput = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
            wrongInputLoopThrough = true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Not a number, please enter a number");
            validatedInput = validate(controlVar); //here is my recursion to return control flow back to the top of the method
        }
    } while (validatedInput < 0 || validatedInput > controlVar);
    return validatedInput;
}
```

Comment: The method will keep calling itself as long as the user keeps entering invalid input. Why use recursion here at all?

Comment: That is not the case. If user inputs char value for example, the method returns void and returns the control flow back to anything that called it, after the exception is thrown and that is behavior I don't want.

Comment: The method can't return `void`, it returns an `int`. If the user inputs a char, then `NumberFormatException` will be thrown and `validate()` will be recursively called.

Comment: @Cinnam I realized my mistake now, but the point of my question is still the same, I wonder why Netbeans thinks there is possibility of infinite recursion in this case

Comment: Because there is - if you keep entering "foo" as input, you will eventually get `StackOverflowError`, because of the recursive calls in the `catch` block.

Comment: So did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You call validate again in your catch, so if it is invalid and you are passing the same value it could catch indefinitely. Instead of catching you should just continue the loop like if it was an integer outside the bounds...